# ArrayList in new Arraylist with attribute

Tags: java, arraylist

I am wondering how to add an `ArrayList` in another `ArrayList` which has a new attribute in Java.  Here is the example :

1. An `ArrayList` named *Person*
2. A new `ArrayList` named *Manager* with the attribute `salary`
3. I want to make the *Person* in *Manager* with the additional attribute salary

The concept is like that, is it possible ?

- manager = ((Person) + Salary)  <----something like that in visual

I hope that makes sense, Thanks :)

Comment: You mean to say You want to use an ArrayList as a Map ?

Comment: This sounds like a classic [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me...

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you referring to what Classes represent?

```
class Person {
//Person stuffs here
}
```

and

```
class Manager extends Person {
   private int salary;
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

use HashMap like below,

Manager->(person->salary)